# Appending a list to a list of lists recursively

Tags: list, prolog

The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows:

I'm given a sorted list where I must pair the first and last items in the list. Then I must pair the 2nd and (last-1) items in the list until the list is either empty or 1 element remains. Then I must return a list of the pairs.

The steps I decided to take for this problem was to first check if the list's length was greater than 1. If it wasn't, then that means we have a list of 0 or 1 elements.

Then I get the first and last items in the given list, delete them from the list, pair them, and then recursively call the same predicate on the new list. Once I've gone all the way down to 0/1 items, I then pop back up and append them to my return list.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to append the pair `L = [first,last]` to my return list, it errors out. My code is listed below.

`T` is my input list.

`first/2` just gets the first item in the list. `pair/3` strips away some info from `P1` and `P2` and then creates `L = [P1,P2]`.

```
getMatches(T,K,ReturnList) :-
   (  length(T,Val),
      Val > 1, 
      first(T,P1), 
      last(T, P2),
      delete(T,P1,G),
      delete(G,P2,H),
      pair(P1,P2,L),
      getMatches(H,K,ReturnList),
      append(L,K,ReturnList)
   ;  first(T,_),
      K = []
   ).
```

An example use:
If `T = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` then 
`ReturnList = [[1,5], [2, 4]]` should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMatches(List, ReturnList) :-        % getMatches/2
    getMatches(List, [], Answer),
    reverse(Answer, ReturnList),
    !.

getMatches(List, ListAns, ListAns) :-  % getMatches/3
    length(List, L),
    L < 2.
getMatches([H | Tail], List, Ans) :-
    last(Tail, Last),
    delete(Tail, Last, NewTail),
    append([[H, Last]], List, NewList),
    getMatches(NewTail, NewList, Ans).
```

And

```
?- getMatches([1,2,3,4,5],X).
X = [[1, 5], [2, 4]].
```

Comment: The two goals `getMatches([a,b,x,x,b,a], [[a,a],[b,b],[x,x]])` and `getMatches([a,b,a,x,b,a], [[a,a],[b,b]])` succeed! That can't be right.
Put the blame on `delete/3` which can break your code if the given list contains duplicate items. Consider `?- delete([1,2,2,2,2,3,2,3], 2, [1,3,3])`.

Answer (score 2):

We define `list_pairs/2` based on the commonly available list predicate [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append).

```
list_pairs([] , []).
list_pairs([_], []).
list_pairs([A,B|Xs0], [A-Z|Yss]) :-
   append(Xs, [Z], [B|Xs0]),
   list_pairs(Xs, Yss).
```

Note we do not represent a pair of `X` and `Y` as a list `[X,Y]`, but rather as a compound `X-Y`. This convention is idiomatic, widespread, and more efficient, too!

Here's the *most general query* of `list_pairs/2`:

```
?- list_pairs(Es, Pss).
   Es = []                 , Pss = []
;  Es = [_]                , Pss = []
;  Es = [A,B]              , Pss = [A-B]
;  Es = [A,_,B]            , Pss = [A-B]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D]          , Pss = [A-D,B-C]
;  Es = [A,B,_,C,D]        , Pss = [A-D,B-C]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,E,F]      , Pss = [A-F,B-E,C-D]
;  Es = [A,B,C,_,D,E,F]    , Pss = [A-F,B-E,C-D]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]  , Pss = [A-H,B-G,C-F,D-E]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,_,E,F,G,H], Pss = [A-H,B-G,C-F,D-E]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a follow-up to [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866271/4609915) and improves it by
avoiding the creation of useless choice-points and by
reducing the Big-O complexity from O(N<sup>2</sup>) to O(N).

```
list_pairs_lin([], []).
list_pairs_lin([X|Xs], XYs) :-
   reverse(Xs, Ys),
   ahead_keys_values_pairs(Xs, [X|Xs], Ys, XYs).

ahead_keys_values_pairs([], _, _, []).
ahead_keys_values_pairs([_|Fs0], [X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X-Y|XYs]) :-
   maybe_ahead(Fs0, Fs),
   ahead_keys_values_pairs(Fs, Xs, Ys, XYs).

maybe_ahead([], []).
maybe_ahead([_|Xs], Xs).
```

Let's run some queries with SWI-Prolog 7.3.15!

Do we still get sound answers when using `list_pairs_lin/2`?

```
?- length(Es, N), numlist(1, N, Es), list_pairs_lin(Es, Pss).
   N = 1, Es = [1]                , Pss = []
;  N = 2, Es = [1,2]              , Pss = [1-2]
;  N = 3, Es = [1,2,3]            , Pss = [1-3]
;  N = 4, Es = [1,2,3,4]          , Pss = [1-4,2-3]
;  N = 5, Es = [1,2,3,4,5]        , Pss = [1-5,2-4]
;  N = 6, Es = [1,2,3,4,5,6]      , Pss = [1-6,2-5,3-4]
;  N = 7, Es = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    , Pss = [1-7,2-6,3-5]
;  N = 8, Es = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  , Pss = [1-8,2-7,3-6,4-5]
;  N = 9, Es = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], Pss = [1-9,2-8,3-7,4-6]
...
```

Yes! What about complexity?

```
?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
true.

?- numlist(1, 5000, _Xs), time(list_pairs(_Xs,_)).
% 6,252,500 inferences, 2.302 CPU in 2.301 seconds (100% CPU, 2716404 Lips)
true ;              % succeeds, but leaves behind useless choicepoint
% 2,503 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 1716259 Lips)
false.              % terminates universally

?- numlist(1, 5000, _Xs), time(list_pairs_lin(_Xs,_)).
% 10,003 inferences, 0.003 CPU in 0.003 seconds (100% CPU, 3680523 Lips)
true.                % succeeds deterministically
```